# VirusTotal api No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, api, virus

I am currently working on a virus scanner and I am using VirusTotal API to scan but it returns an error

here is the code:

```
def Send_File(file):
    params = {'API Key': API_KEY}
    files = {'file': ('check.py', open('check.py', 'rb'))}
  response=requests.post('https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan', 
    files=files, params=params)
    json_response = response.json()
```

Comment: Can you please attach that error?

Comment: @kvk30   raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
                ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: I think you need to use, `json.load(response)` instead of response.json().

Comment: @kvk30 no it gives me this error: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @DanielSaada You need wrap params in Json as  params = json.dumps(params) and then pass the params to request.